# О переиздании Грамматики-80 в 2005 году и о новой «Русской грамматике»

Tags: грамматика, общие-вопросы

**Вопросы:**

1) **Были ли внесены в новое издание 2005 года** какие-либо изменения?

2) **Это  вариант какого года?** http://rusgram.narod.ru/

Из предисловия:  "Русская грамматика" является описательной и **нормативной**.

3) **О классификации частей речи и вводных словах** (эти сведения следует считать нормативными для всех пользователей русского языка?)

Из раздела "Морфология"

Все слова группируются в классы, называемые частями речи. В современном русском языке существует **десять частей речи:** 1) имя существительное; 2) местоимение­существительное; 3) имя прилагательное; 4) имя числительное; 5) наречие; 6) глагол; 7) предлог; 8) союз; 9) частицы; 10) междометие.

Из раздела "Синтаксис"

К вводным словам и сочетаниям слов относится довольно обширная и легко пополняющаяся группировка **лексико-синтаксических единиц** - словоформ и в разной степени устойчивых сочетаний, выражающих отношение к сообщаемому или его характеристику: экспрессивную реакцию на сообщение; подчеркивание, выделение какой-то его части; характеристику сообщаемого с точки зрения его связей и отношений, достоверности или недостоверности; по характеру протекания во времени; отнесение сообщения к его источнику

4) Как проходит подготовка к **новому изданию «Русская грамматика – 4.0»?**

http://konferencii.ru/info/113114